# Leaflet and jQuery mobile won't cooperate

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile, leaflet

everyone. I'm working on a mobile app for a nature reserve (the old map is currently built with flash), and I'm having trouble with jQuery mobile and leaflet. As it stands, I can only get either the leaflet map or the jQuery navbar. Below is the html section:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>UW Arboretum</title>

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,   user-scalable=no">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/logo.png"/>


<!-- <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320" />  -->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js">    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/leaflet.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

    <script src="js/leaflet-src.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/jquery-ui/js/jquery-ui-1.10.1.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div id="map">
</div><!--map-->

<div data-role="footer" 
data-position="fixed">
<div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#abcdefg" class="ui-state-persist" data-icon="arrow-r">abc</a></li>
        <li><a href="#abcdefg" class="ui-state-persist" data-icon="arrow-r">def</a></li>
        <li><a href="#abcdefg" class="ui-state-persist" data-icon="arrow-r">ghi</a></li>
        <li><a href="#abcdefg" class="ui-state-persist" data-icon="arrow-r">jkl</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!--footer-->




</body>

</html>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you create a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with your code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4WhKL/

Answer (score 0):

You have double jQuery loading:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Also try using newest versions of jQuery and jQuery Mobile

Comment: Thanks for the response. Still not getting the map and the jQuery to co-exist, however.

Comment: Maybe try:  
  <div data-role="page">
         <div data-role="content">
          <div id="map">
          </div>
         </div>
         <!-- rest of html code -->
        </div>

Comment: In Firefox you could use Firebug extension to check for javascript errors

Comment: In firebug I'm getting an error, TypeError: container is null, but it's in reference to leaflet-src.js.

Comment: Going to that line says...if (container._leaflet) {
throw new Error("Map container is already initialized.");
}